# problems with the cms made simple modules cart and orders

Tags: cart, orders, cmsmadesimple

I'm currently building my first e-commerce website. I used the modules products, cart and orders but without paiement option. People can add articles to their cart, and confirm the reservation by filling up billing and shipping informations. After confirmation, they get an email saying that the reservation is confirmed and that the owner will contact them asap for shipping and payment options. It works but I still have a few issues :

-The client confirmation mail works but the admin doesn't receive a confirmation mail with the order. I configured CMSMailer and I put the email in the configuration pannel of the e-commerce module.

-I want to put an image from the article in the cart. here is my code :

`<img src="{$oneitem->file_location}/{$oneitem->fields.image->thumbnail}" alt="{$oneitem->value}" />`

The path is right to the / but he doesn't find the image in the product folder. I don't understand why. I need to get that :

`<img src="/uploads/Products/product_1/thumb_mobilier_table_appoint.jpg" alt="">`

but I only get that :

`<img src="/uploads/Products/product_1/" alt="">`

-For some products, I want to have more than one image, so that I have a little photo gallery with 2 or 3 images and the possibility to zoom in each image. How can I do that? With the photo gallery module? And how can I integrate it in the products module?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the values of the fields and construct the link with it.